# Is there a solution to this problem in PHP?

Tags: php, xampp

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected variable "$servername" in C:\xampp\htdocs\crud\connection.php on line 3

I met this line when I run my PHP code. Any help please?

I was creating a form to link with a database using PHP. The connection was supposed to be successful per the video I followed but this was my encounter.

Comment: Before someone can help you, they need to see the PHP code you're trying to run - especially the section that contains a $servername variable. Can you edit some code into your question?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you need help debugging code that you have written, you must post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and explain the specific problem with your code.

Comment: Ooh, yes! there is a solution to this problem.

Comment: This is a very not awesome question title. It would describe a million other PHP pages. Please [edit] your title to narrowly describe your problem.